# Would it be better to use closures for event handling instead of eval()?

Tags: php, event-handling

I'm making an event handler for a class, but I was wondering if it would be better to use closures instead of evaluation of code?

My only reason for using eval() is simply because it is able to access everything within the class (and it's really, really unsafe :D), but I don't know if closures can.

if I did something like this:

```
<?php
    class SomethingCool {
        protected $handlers;

        public function addHandler($cmd, closure $func) {
            $this->handlers[$cmd][] = $func;
        }

        public function handle($cmd) {
            if(!isset($this->handlers[$cmd]))
                return false;
            foreach($this->handlers[$cmd] as $func)
                $func();
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    $wut = new SomethingCool();
    $wut->addHandler('lol', function() use($wut) {
                                $wut->handle('lol');
                            }
                    );
?>
```

Would it execute without error?
I would test it myself, but I'm unable to at the moment.

Comment: Apart from the obvious error arising from dereferencing `unset` ...

Comment: What is `$this` supposed to reference to?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#107949

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write handlers using `eval`, you'll end up writing code like this:

```
$wut->addHandler('lol', '$this->handle(\'lol\');');
```

Apart from the obviously terrible problems with escaping quotes and broken syntax highlighting in your editor, this introduces the problem of ambiguous dependencies. What does `$this` refer to in your code? It does not work literally as is in the code, it depends on being evaluated within a certain context. This makes code a real mess.

The alternative is dependency injection:

```
$wut->addHandler('lol', function (SomethingCool $sc) {
    $sc->handle('lol');
});
```

When calling this handler, `SomethingCool` will inject itself as a function argument. That's a lot more robust. It means you can hand this callback around to other contexts and do whatever you want behind the scenes, the callback does not depend on being evaluated within a certain context anymore.

Alternatively, use a closure:

```
$wut->addHandler('lol', function () use ($wut) {
    $wut->handle('lol');
});
```

This has the same benefit of you being sure where your dependency comes from and knowing that you can depend on it.

So yes, *anything* is better than `eval`.

Comment: ooh, that seems like the best bet imo. 
thanks for the input dewd, I'll test this when I am at home.

And LOL yeah, why do you think I wanted to leave eval()? it's evil.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the instance of your `SomethingCool` to each handler?

```
public function handle($cmd) 
{
    if (!isset($this->handlers[$cmd])) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($this->handlers[$cmd] as $func)
        $func($this); // pass ourself to each handler
    }
}

$wut->addHandler('lol', function(SomethingCool $obj) {
    // $obj refers to the SomethingCool instance
});

$wut->handle('lol');
```

Btw, if you also want to be able to remove handlers, you could also use `SplObjectStorage` for each command category.